# Do I have to book accommodation for the entire stay of a long-term visa before applying for it?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications, proof-of-accommodation

I am going to be staying in the Netherlands for three months. The Embassy needs an itinerary for accommodation. I am still looking for a room (in a flat) to stay in so I will have to just provide a itinerary for a hotel.

Do I need to show accommodation for the whole period (three months) or should I just book for two weeks or so?

The hotels don't allow a period of more than a month and I don't think it looks realistic anyway to say you are staying at a hotel for three whole months!

What should I do?

Comment: You can try searching for things like *short term apartment rental amsterdam.*

Comment: I think this is a somewhat valid question if rephrased. We might even have an answer already on the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The embassy is more interested knowing whether you can afford to pay your accommodation costs for three months than the exact location where you are staying.

The best option would be to have a preliminary booking for a short-stay apartment or the like for the full three months, complete with a cost estimate and proof of funds to pay for it.  But you could also state that you're staying in a hotel for the first X weeks, cost €Y and here's the booking, and will look for a local apartment that you expect to cost €Z/month for the rest, and here's a rental site showing what you can get for that price.

Comment: How can I show them that I amexpecting an apartment costing Z using documents ? Do you mean I should just print a few offers off rental sites ? Notice that I haven't found a website that allows you to have a preliminary rental of a flat; you have to pay and sign a contract.

Comment: Yes, basically.  There are apartment hotels that offer hotel-like flexibility, but they also tend to cost more.

Comment: Try searching for [serviced apartments](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=serviced+apartments+amsterdam).